# Message Bubble Cut Off in TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a chat feature in my app, but the cells are getting cut off.  I've reviewed the Ray Wenderlich tutorial and the SO questions, but I think my problem is that I combine code with auto layout and I'm missing something (for instance, I don't put a label for the message text on the storyboard, but I do put the imageView).  Here's what it looks like when I run it:

[image]

Here is the code for the tableView setup:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Other code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Get a preconfigured messageCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.messageCell) as! MessageCell
        // Send the message to it for set up.
        cell.setMessage(message: messages[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

And here is the setMessage function in the custom cell:

```
    @IBOutlet var messageImage: UIImageView!

    func setMessage(message: Message) {

    if message.who == "me" {
        // User wrote this message, show it on the right in blue as an outgoing message.
        let text = message.txt

        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.text = text

        let constrainRect = CGSize(width: 0.66 * self.frame.width,
                                   height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = text.boundingRect(with: constrainRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: label.font!], context: nil)
        label.frame.size = CGSize(width: ceil(boundingBox.width), height: ceil(boundingBox.height))

        let bubbleImageSize = CGSize(width: label.frame.width + 28, height: label.frame.height + 20)

        messageImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(
            x: self.frame.width - bubbleImageSize.width - 20,
            y: self.frame.height - (bubbleImageSize.height),
            width: bubbleImageSize.width,
            height: bubbleImageSize.height))

        let bubbleImage = UIImage(named: "outgoing-message-bubble")?
            .resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 17, left: 21, bottom: 17, right: 21), resizingMode: .stretch)
            .withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)

        messageImage.image = bubbleImage

        self.addSubview(messageImage)
        label.center = messageImage.center
        self.addSubview(label)

    } else {
        // Other person wrote this message.  Show it on the left in gray.
    }
}
```

There are no constraints on messageImage, but I have tried it with constraints of zero around it and the result is the same.  I've run the code with breaks and confirmed the sizes are all accurate for the text and the bubble image.  But the content view of the cell is cutting off the height to a standard cell size.  I've worked on this for over a day.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think problem is in setMessage function where you are calculating constrainRect values. 'self.frame.width' will not return actual screen size because layout is not adjusted according to screen yet.
I think you should use 'UIScreen.main.bounds.width' to get screen width.

Comment: This has the same result.  The problem seems to be in dynamically adjusting the height of the cell.  The break shows the calcs are good, but the cells are being chopped to fit some standard size cell.

Comment: You are not adding any constraints. For dynamic layout you need to add constraints.  Auto layout will calculate cell height on base of those constraints.

Comment: Which elements need a constraint?  messageImage, label or bubbleImage?  Also, should I add them with code?  If so, what method do I use?  Thanks!

Comment: It is recommended to add constraint to all elements. I can be done by code as well as interface builder.

Comment: I am trying to add constraints by code below self.addSubview(label).  I am getting the error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'  Is there someplace else I should put code constraints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198087/discussion-between-abdulrehman-warraich-and-tm-lynch).